# Generated enemies don't display properly

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to add to my platformer with some PVP mechanics. The first thing I decided to do is to add a generation of enemies. After creating an Enemy class and a function to create a list with enemies' information, I started my test by trying to blit my enemies to the screen, but the problem is that sometimes they blit once, and sometimes they don't blit at all. Sometimes they blit 50% of the time. Why?
Here are all parts of the code that retouch enemies generation and display.

```
def generate_enemy(player, enemy_group, image_list):
    for i in range(3):
        enemy = Enemy(player, image_list)
        enemy_group.add(enemy)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.momentum = 0
        self.speed = 7
        self.health = 100
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, player, image_list):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image_list[0]
        self.spawn = []
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 1:
            self.x = player.hitbox.x + random.randint(50, 60)
            self.spawn.append(player.hitbox.x + random.randint(50, 60))
        else:
            self.x = player.hitbox.x - random.randint(50, 60)
            self.spawn.append(player.hitbox.x - random.randint(50, 60))
        self.y = player.hitbox.y
        self.width = self.image.get_width()
        self.height = self.image.get_height()
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.momentum = 0
        self.speed = random.randint(3,6)
        self.health = 50
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False

WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1300, 650
FPS = 60

Enemy_animations = [pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images\\enemy_animation\\enemy_0.png")).convert_alpha(), (64, 47)),
                        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images\\enemy_animation\\enemy_1.png")).convert_alpha(), (64, 47)),
                        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images\\enemy_animation\\enemy_2.png")).convert_alpha(), (57, 90)),
                        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images\\enemy_animation\\enemy_3.png")).convert_alpha(), (72, 51)),
                        pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("images\\enemy_animation\\enemy_4.png")).convert_alpha(), (87, 57))]


Enemy_Group = pygame.sprite.Group()
Slid = Player(0, 0, Slid_Current_Image)
        
display.blit(Slid_Current_Image, (Slid.hitbox.x - scroll[0], Slid.hitbox.y - scroll[1]))

for enemy in Enemy_Group:
    display.blit(enemy.image, (enemy.hitbox.x, enemy.hitbox.y))

if frame_counter % 300 == 0:
    generate_enemy(Slid, Enemy_Group, Enemy_animations)
        
surface = pygame.transform.scale(display, (WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT))
window.blit(surface, (0, 0))
```

Comment: The Enemy_Group starts as an empty sprite group. You might want to check frame_counter and verify that generate_enemy is being called when you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, generate_enemy is called when I check frame_counteri is multiple of 300, as I said the problem is the fact that enemies aren't displayed properly: sometimes they blit only one small group, sometimes they don't blit at all.

Comment: What is `surface`?  Is it painting over the list of `enemy` previously drawn?  (There is not enough code in the question to see what the problem is.)

Comment: "surface" is the way to scale all the elements on the window with the window itself. It 
 stores the "display" variable, but scaled to "WINDOW_WIDTH" and "WINDOW_HEIGHT".

Comment: @Sukurima - Did you get this working?  There doesn't seem to be anything obviously incorrect.